# Onde e como salvar o token de autenticação de API's?

Tags: angularjs, angular, asp.net-web-api, iis, token

Olá, eu estou com uma aplicação angular, que irá consumir uma `API`. Para que isso aconteça, eu devo mandar um `POST` para outra `API`, que serve apenas para gerar um `token` que eu irei passar em todas as outras requisições. A minha dúvida é a seguinte: após eu gerar esse `token`, onde eu devo salvá-lo? A primeira coisa que vem a mente é salvar diretamente no banco, mas não aparenta ser o recomendado. O que normalmente é feito nessa situação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende to TTL (*[time-to-live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live)*, ou *tempo de vida*) do token.

- Se o token for de curta duração: Mantenha-o em memória (ou *cache*) apenas.
- Se o token for de longa duração: Armazene-o em banco, associado ao usuário (ou processo) que o obteu.

Lembre-se que a maioria dos serviços que trabalham com autorização via *token* podem retornar um `401 Unauthorized` a qualquer momento, e o processo de re-autenticação para qualquer TTL é geralmente o mesmo.

Comment: No caso, ele é de curta duração (15 min), e o servidor é um IIS. Você poderia me dizer, como eu armazenaria esse token, em memória, em uma aplicação Angular?

Comment: @GuilhermeNunes se for um token por sessão, crie um service para armazenar e compartilhar o valor entre os módulos da sua aplicação Angular. Se for por usuário e seu modelo permitir que um usuário utilize dois ou mais dispositivos você precisará compartilhar o token com seu backend.